# pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file ki8r): Font ki8r at 486 not found

Tags: miktex

I downloaded MiKTeX 2.9 (x64) and installed into Window 7 (64-bit). I encountered the following message.

{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file ki8r): Font ki8r at 486 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

However, when I installed into Window 10 (64-bit) in my office computer, there is no this problem.

I appreciate any instruction to resolve it on Win7 in advance.

Thank you so much.

Comment: *Normally* this means that you have user map files which need to be updated with `updmap`. As you didn't provide a test file I can't say more